# Count users of each department

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following layout :

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | name      | department  |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|   1| John      | Finance     |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|   2| Bob       | Optics      |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|   3| Jill      | Finance     |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|   4| Jake      | Finance     |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|   5| Mike      | Support     |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to get the sum of all the people in each department :

```
+-----------+-------------+
| people    | department  |
+-----------+-------------+
|          3| Finance     |
+-----------+-------------+
|          1| Optics      |
+-----------+-------------+
|          1| Support     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I am having trouble constructing a right query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(name),department FROM table GROUP BY department
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT departmetn, Count(*) as people FROM table Group by departmetn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
 SELECT COUNT(name) AS people,department FROM table GROUP BY department
```